# Group of order $1575$ is solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $1575 = 3^25^27$. Show that $G$ is solvable.

So far, my idea is to show that $n_7, n_5 $ or $n_3$ equals $1$, so that there exists a unique Sylow subgroup of order $7, 5^2$ or $3^2$ which is normal.

For example, suppose that $n_7 = 1$. Then, I can take the quotient group $H = G/P_7$, where $P_7$ is a $7$-Sylow subgroup. Then, $|H| = 3^25^2$. Now, in $H$, we have that $n_5=1$, so there exists a unique $5$-Sylow subgroup in $H$. Then, $H/P_5$ has order $3^2$, which is abelian. Hence, $P_5$ and $H/P_5$ are solvable groups, whence $H$ is solvable. Applying the same argument on $H = G/P_7$, since $P_7\leq G$ is solvable, then $G$ is solvable.

However, I can not make sure that $n_7=1$, since $n_7$ could be $n_7 = 15 $ or $n_7 = 225$. The old trick of assuming that $n_7>1$ would give me more elements of order $7$ than the number of elements of $G$  doesn't work here.

Is there any other idea I could use to rule out the cases $n_7 = 15$, $n_7 = 225?$ I am aware of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625520/group-of-order-1575-having-a-normal-sylow-3-subgroup-is-abelian), but in this case it is assumed that we have a normal $3$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: I guess you are not allowed to use the deep theorem that every finite group with odd order is solvable ?

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about this topic. However, I will note that there are other questions about groups of order $1575=3^2 5^2 7$  on this site, such as here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625520/group-of-order-1575-having-a-normal-sylow-3-subgroup-is-abelian?noredirect=1&lq=1 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228967/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-1575-with-normal-sylow-3-subgroup-then-show-that?noredirect=1&lq=1. Some results from there may or may not be useful or relevant for this question: I have no idea. I just thought it is worth mentioning.

Comment: Since $1575 \not\mid 9!$, if $G$ were simple there would be no subgroup of index $\leq 9$, hence no subgroup of index $< 15$ (since $105$ is the largest factor of $1575$ no greater than $\frac{1575}{10}$). At this point a good option might be to study the normalizers of intersections of Sylow $p$-subgroups and see if you can force one to have order $> 105$; I would try $p = 5$ first.

Comment: I'd follow Travis' advice to start by assuming there are 21 Sylow 5-subgroups. As 25 does not divide 21-1 there are two Sylow 5-subgroup that intersect in a subgroup $H$ of order 5 (Hint: Look at the action by conjugation of a Sylow 5-subgroup on the set of Sylow 5-subgroups to get $H$). The normalizer $N$ of $H$ in $G$ contains at least two Sylow 5-subgroups, so there are 21, and $N$ is either $G$ (and hence $H$ normal in $G$) or $N$ has index 3 in $G$, hence is normal in $G$ ($G$ has odd order, take the action of $G$ on the cosets of $N$), which implies that $H$ is normal in $G$, as ...

Comment: ... $H$ is characteristic in $N$. So you can factor out $H$, and the quotient of order $315$ you should be able to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

Undoubtedly there are many ways to settle this. The one outlined in the comments by Travis Willse and j.p. may be the simplest, and I am most certainly the wrong person to hunt for *the simplest arguent* (if we can agree on a metric :-). I proffer the following less general alternative that I cooked up.

---

As a starting point I also use the action of $G$ on the set $X$ of Sylow $5$-subgroups. In the interesting case $n_5=|X|=21$, so if we fix a Sylow $5$-subgroup $P$, we can assume that $N_G(P)$ has order $|G|/n_5=75$.

A useful observation about a group of order $75$ is that either it is abelian, or it is isomorphic to the semidirect product $\Bbb{F}_5^2\rtimes C_3$, with the conjugation action of an element or order three on the vector space $\Bbb{F}_5^2$ represented by a matrix of order three *that has no eigenvalues in the prime field*. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531504/11619) for a proof of this fact.

A consequence of the italicized observation is that either A) $N_G(P)$ is abelian, or B) $N_G(P)$ has no subgroups of order fifteen. I shall deal with these two cases separately.

**B:** If $N_G(P)$ has no subgroups of index five, it follows that the conjugation action of $N_G(P)$ on $X$ cannot have orbits of size five. That leaves orbits of size $1,3,15$ as possibilities. Actually size $3$ is impossible as the Sylow $5$-subgroups in such an orbit would be normalized by $P$, and an elementary fact is that $P$ is the only Sylow $5$-subgroup it normalizes. Try as we may, we cannot build the set $X$ with $21$ elements out of such orbits unless there are several orbits of size one, a possibility excluded by the same reasoning. So case B is impossible.

**A:** And we can assume that $N_G(P)$ is abelian. Let $x\in N_G(P)$ be an element of order three. Consider its centralizer $C_G(x)$. We know that $P\le C_G(x)$. But all the Sylow $3$-subgroups have order $3^2$, and are thus known to be abelian. Therefore the order of $C_G(x)$ is also divisible by nine. So either $C_G(x)=G$, or $[G:C_G(x)]=7$. In the latter case we get a non-trivial homomorphism $\phi:G\to S_7$ from the transitive action of $G$ on the cosets of $C_G(x)$. As $5^2\nmid 7!$ this homomorphism has a kernel of order $m$ such that $5\mid m$ and $m\mid 3^2\cdot 5^2$.

---

So it follows that either $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order divisible by five, or $3\mid |Z(G)|$. Leaving the rest to you. The most taxing case seems to be that of $|G/N|=315$, but [there is another useful old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4191205/11619). [The case of $G/Z(G)$ of order $525$ has also been dealt with](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3028914/11619).

Comment: It may be that there is too much duplication in this, in which case I apologize for deteriorating the signal-to-noise ratio of the site. The upshot here is the use of known structure of groups of order $75$ that I find somewhat interesting. You be the judge.

Comment: The fact about groups of order $75$ generalizes to groups of order $pq^2$, $p<q$ both primes such that $p\nmid q-1$ but we allow $p\mid q^2-1$ (so $p\mid q+1$).